# Filter combobox5 items depending on combobox4 selection

Tags: c#, filter, combobox

I would like to filter my combobox's based on the previous combobox selection
for example, 
combobox4 contains - shoes, watches, tvs.
combobox5 would contain - rockport, addidas //shoe selection- 
                          tagheuer, rolex //watch selection -
                          Sony, Samsung // Tv selection.

if i was to select tv's in combo4, i would like combo5 to filter down to just the tv selection

apologies in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology, I am just beginning with C#

**edit** 
at the moment the values have been set using the actual form design on combobox properties - Items.
I can change this if needed and hard code it 
Not using any sql.

Comment: We need a lot more information than supplied. Post some of the work you have already done. Are you binding the first combobox by SQL? Or is it hardcoded? Is this in ASP.NET or Windows Forms? WPF? Please edit with more detail and code.

Comment: Take a look into AJAX, there's a lot of this on the internet.

Comment: Hi @AthanasiosKaragiannis, Its not currently hardcoded, just added using the win form design.
Its Windows Forms im using.

Comment: Hi, @Andyheron you can looking for "cascade combobox c# or cascade select html", you're using c# mvc or c# asp.net? in mvc you can do it with ajax response and in asp.net you can do it with AutoPostBack="true", tell me and I try to create an example for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution I decided to bind your combobox using the code instead of through the designer. I think this is best since it would be easy edit later on.

```
protected void bindMainComboBox()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Shoes");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Watches");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Tvs");
}
```

You will want to call this on form load.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bindMainComboBox();
}
```

You will want to assign a index changed event handler on your first combobox. Incase you don't know how to do that. Right click on the combobox, click Properties. Now in your properties window, you want to click the yellow electric bolt thingy("Events"). Scroll down till you find SelectedIndexChanged and double click the empty field to the right of it. This will create a new section in your code to handle the event.

Here is what mine looks like. I store the text of the first combobox and pass it to a new method which will bind it similar to how the first combobox did.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
    bindSecondComboBox(selectedValue);
}
```

This is the method. Simple if & else ifs to handle the different selections and bind the second combobox accordingly.

```
protected void bindSecondComboBox(string selValue)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
    if (selValue == "Shoes")
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Rockport");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Addidas");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Nike");
    }
    else if (selValue == "Watches")
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Tagheuer");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Rolex");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Victus");
    }
    else if (selValue == "Tvs")
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Sony");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Samsung");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Toshiba");
    }
}
```

**This is very basic code, while there are dozens of ways to do this. Using this method makes it easy to edit it later to become more complex and capable.**

Since ComboBox takes in objects, you can literally store anything you want in them, I would look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c7a82a6a-763e-424b-84e0-496caa9cfb4d/how-add-a-item-to-combobox?forum=winforms) for an example of how they created a new Items class to handle a text/value pair. You can pair this with datatables, SQL, arrays, list, or anything which you can use to load your data without hard coding it like my example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. I'm not quite ready to explore the SQL side so this is perfect to help me move forward.

Comment: @Andyheron I'm glad it helped, please make sure to mark answers as "the answer" so the question appears done and not pending still and so others can find the solution.